# Rails acceptace tests - stubbing out external service calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm wondering if it's possible to stub out external services.
I have the following call to external service in my app:

```
bitly = Bitly.new("someuser", "123key")
bitly.shorten("www.example.com/my_model/#{@my_model.id}")
```

Would it be possible to stub out Bitly for every call to this service during my acceptance tests?

Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out Webmock, https://github.com/bblimke/webmock.  One thing I've liked about it is that it'll raise an error for any outbound http request that hasn't been stubbed (and also provides generated example code to stub the request).  It's also well documented.

Edit: Alternatively, instead of stubbing out the actual http request, you could stub out the shorten method:

```
bitly = Bitly.new("someuser", "123key")
bitly.stub(:shorten).and_return("some value")
bitly.shorten("<some url>").should == "some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always redefine the class, and create a new `shorten` method that accepts a URL. You'll also need to return a value that makes sense to your code:

```
class Bitly

  def initialize(p1, p2)
    @p1, @p2 = p1, p2 # in case it's important to remember them
  end

  def shorten(url)
    "some return value"
  end

end

bitly = Bitly.new("someuser", "123key")
bitly.shorten("www.example.com/my_model/#{@my_model.id}")
```

Even if you included the normal Bitly files prior to that declaration, any code following it will use the redefined class and methods.

There's probably a lot of other, better, ways to do it, but that's quick (and dirty) and works simply.

Sometimes you can identify a particular method that bottlenecks all the external service's I/O, replace it, and take advantage of everything else the code has to offer. That is one of the things I think is cool about Ruby.